# how to restore old backup of plone site

Tags: plone

A couple years ago I backed up my plone site by making a copy of the zope directory cantaining other directories such as var, Products, etc, Extension, bin, log...
I think the Plone version was 2.1.3 but I am not certain.  I would like to know how I can restore my plone site from this backup.  I can't find any documentation on restoring from this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Francis

Answer (score 2):

If it is really Plone 2.1.x, you can use a buildout like this one:

- http://dist.aclark.net/build/plone/2.1.x/buildout.cfg

The procedure could like something like this (assuming you have Python 2.4 installed):

```
$ easy_install-2.4 zc.buildout
$ mkdir plone
$ mkdir plone/products
$ cd plone
$ buildout init
$ curl http://dist.aclark.net/build/plone/2.1.x/extends.cfg > buildout.cfg  
$ bin/buildout
```

Now copy your old Data.fs to var/filestorage, and:

```
$ bin/instance fg
```

You may also need to copy over the contents of the Products directory (to plone/products) and configure them via buildout, by editing your buildout.cfg file to look like this:

```
[buildout]
extends = http://dist.aclark.net/build/plone/2.1.x/buildout.cfg

[instance]
products += products
```

Then run bin/buildout again.

Or, check for an installer here: http://dist.plone.org/archive/ and repeat the same process of copying in the Data.fs and add-on products.